# Using Google Material Icons in UWP App

Tags: javascript, angular, uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I'm currently working on a JavaScript based UWP app for the Windows Store and I'm taking the code I wrote in Angular 2 for my web app and transitioning it directly into the UWP app.  My last hurdle before making it live is that none of the material icons that I am using are being displayed within the UWP App when I am testing.

For Reference: [Live Website](http://bitcointracker.us/)

Link tag within the html page

material-icons.css file content.  I used VS 2015 to convert the font files over to base64.  I have the same end result whether or not I do this conversion

```
@font-face
{
    font-family: 'Material Icons';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: url('data:application/vnd.ms-fontobject;base64,{TRUNCATED} */
    src: local('Material Icons'),
    local('MaterialIcons-Regular'),
    url('data:font/x-woff2;base64,{TRUNCATED}'),
    url('data:font/x-woff;base64,{TRUNCATED}'),
    url('data:application/octet-stream;base64,{TRUNCATED}');
}

.material-icons
{
    font-family: 'Material Icons';
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 1;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    word-wrap: normal;
    direction: ltr;
    -webkit-font-feature-settings: 'liga';
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

Code within angular component that is not displaying properly

```
<md-icon>dialpad</md-icon>
```

TLDR; How do I get Google's Material Icons to display properly in a UWP Application?

Answer (score 2):

> How do I get Google's Material Icons to display properly in a UWP Application?

For UWP Application, if you want to self-host the icon font, you need to use WinRT specific URI schemes in your css. For details of WinRT schemes, please refer to [URI schemes that are specific to a Windows Runtime app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Foundation.Uri).

For Example: If you self-host the icon font in your application, then you need to use the `ms-appx:///` scheme:

1. copy the [icon font](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/tree/master/iconfont) to your application folder:

[image]

2. Then add the following CSS in `default.css`:

   ```
   @font-face {
   font-family: 'Material Icons';
   font-style: normal;
   font-weight: 400;
   src: url(ms-appx:///iconfont/MaterialIcons-Regular.eot); /* For IE6-8 */
   src: local('Material Icons'), local('MaterialIcons-Regular'), 
       url(ms-appx:///iconfont/MaterialIcons-Regular.woff2) format('woff2'), 
       url(ms-appx:///iconfont/MaterialIcons-Regular.woff) format('woff'), 
       url(ms-appx:///iconfont/MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf) format('truetype');
   }


   .material-icons {
       font-family: 'Material Icons';
       font-weight: normal;
       font-style: normal;
       font-size: 24px; /* Preferred icon size */
       display: inline-block;
       line-height: 1;
       text-transform: none;
       letter-spacing: normal;
       word-wrap: normal;
       white-space: nowrap;
       direction: ltr;
       /* Support for all WebKit browsers. */
       -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
       /* Support for Safari and Chrome. */
       text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
       /* Support for Firefox. */
       -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
       /* Support for IE. */
       font-feature-settings: 'liga';
   }
   ```
3. Use the Material Icon:

   ```
   <i class="material-icons">dialpad</i>
   ```

I didn't try the Angular 2 version Material Icon, but I believe it can also work fine.

Comment: +1 Thanks for this, I also had to use the non-modern set of material icons, so instead of `<md-icon>dialpad</md-icon>` it was `<md-icon>&#xE0BC;</md-icon